# Apply function to all inputs of a list dictionary

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

I am trying to run a function `pre_process` on a list input `k1_tweets_filtered['text']`.
however, the function only seems to work on one input at a time i.e. `k1_tweets_filtered[1]['text']`. 
I want the function to run on all inputs of `k1_tweets_filtered['text']`.

I have tried to use loops, however, the loop only outputs the words of the first input .

I am wondering if this is the right approach as to how I can apply this to the rest of the inputs

This is the question I am trying to solve and what I have coded so far.

Write your code to pre-process and clean up all tweets 
stored in the variable `k1_tweets_filtered`, `k2_tweets_filtered` and `k3_tweets_filtered` using the 
function `pre_process()` to result in new variables `k1_tweets_processed`, `k2_tweets_processed` 
and `k3_tweets_processed`.

```
for x in range(len(k1_tweets_filtered)): 
    tweet_k1 = k1_tweets_filtered[x]['text']
    x+=1
    k1_tweets_processed = pre_process(tweet_k1)
```

The function `pre_process` is below, however, I know that this is correct, as it was given to me.

```
def remove_non_ascii(s): return "".join(i for i in s if ord(i)<128)
def pre_process(doc):
    """
    pre-processes a doc
      * Converts the tweet into lower case,
      * removes the URLs,
      * removes the punctuations
      * tokenizes the tweet
      * removes words less that 3 characters
    """

    doc = doc.lower()
    # getting rid of non ascii codes
    doc = remove_non_ascii(doc)

    # replacing URLs
    url_pattern = "http://[^\s]+|https://[^\s]+|www.[^\s]+|[^\s]+\.com|bit.ly/[^\s]+"
    doc = re.sub(url_pattern, 'url', doc) 

    # removing dollars and usernames and other unnecessary stuff
    userdoll_pattern = "\$[^\s]+|\@[^\s]+|\&[^\s]+|\*[^\s]+|[0-9][^\s]+|\~[^\s]+"
    doc = re.sub(userdoll_pattern, '', doc)


    # removing punctuation
    punctuation = r"\(|\)|#|\'|\"|-|:|\\|\/|!|\?|_|,|=|;|>|<|\.|\@"
    doc = re.sub(punctuation, ' ', doc)

    return [w for w in doc.split() if len(w) > 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
k1_tweets_processed = []
for i in range(len(k1_tweets_filtered)): 
    tweet_k1 = k1_tweets_filtered[i]['text']
    k1_tweets_processed.append(pre_process(tweet_k1))
```

When you iterate it is better to use i,j for variable name, and if you have "for i n range(10)" you should not increment it inside your loop. And previously you set k1_tweets_processed to single preprocessed text instead of creating list and adding new texts to it.